# xpath expression no text in children

Tags: xml, xpath

I have bookstore xml.

```
<book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book_blank>
    <title lang="en"></title>
    <author></author>
    <year></year>
    <price></price>    
</book_blank>
```

I am trying find an XPATH expression which will select those elements which have no text children, i.e. output will like be

```
<book category="CHILDREN">
</book>

<book_blank>
    <title lang="en"></title>
    <author></author>
    <year></year>
    <price></price>    
</book_blank>
```

Comment: What xpath expressions have you tried?

Comment: I am trying but not working //not(contains(text(), '(default)'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the expression `tag[not(text()[normalize-space()])]` to test for a tag with no text.  To test for a missing tag use `[not(tag)]`.

For your specific case (I am assuming that  should really be )

```
 /book[not(author) or author[not(text()[normalize-space()])]]
```

The above will find any `book` that has a blank author or is missing the author.

Comment: +1 never thought of the `[normalize-space()]` trick.  But won't that include text nodes that are whitespace-only?

Comment: @harpo, yes it will.  I assume  that this is desired behaviour.  `<author>   </author>' should be treated as empty (I think).

Comment: Right... I mean, *that* predicate will include whitespace only, before the `not`.  In other words, as far as XPath converting strings to booleans, whitespace is the same as non-whitespace content; only blank will be falsy.